# Methods and references overflow

Tags: php, function, methods, reference, overflow

I'm working on a project and I have a method called `View::import`. This receives two arguments `string name, reference mixed value` (*I wrote thus to better understand, but is PHP!*).

Currently, to call this method, I need to do:

```
    $test = 1;
    View::import('test', $test);
```

Works very fine, but I like to call **too**:

```
    View::import('test', 1);
```

For static cases, that I don't need replace original variable content, only "store on the fly".

The full method is:

```
    private static $globals;
    public static function import($key, &$value){
        self::$globals->{$key} = &$value;
    }
```

If I change to:

```
    public static function import($key, $value){ // no-reference
```

I can't change original values, on some cases. And I won't make a new method like `import_static` or similar.

Exists someway to *overflow* this method? (I know that PHP don't support this perfectly).

The closest code is:

```
    View::import('test', $temporaryTest = 1);
```

But I think that is a big *workarround*, not?

Comment: You can't do this. Or reference or value, something 1. `$temporaryTest = 1` will pass result of this assignment (1), not reference.

Comment: In the sure, will pass the own `$temporaryTest` (that is equal `1`). That is how I works currently. (works in PHP 5.3, at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can '*overflow*' this by changing the design of your code. For example do something like this:

```
public static function import($key, $value){
    self::$globals->{$key} = $value;
    // do something with $value
    return $value;
}
```

and then you will be able to write:

```
$test = 1;
$test = View::import('test', $test);
```

as well as:

```
View::import('test', 1);
```

---

Below is some alternative solution, that actually involves creating new, but meaningful method:

```
// Your old method
public static function import($key, $value){
    self::$globals->{$key} = $value;
}
// Your new method
public static function bind($key, &$value){
    self::$globals->{$key} = &$value;
}
```

Applying the above it will be easy for you to see what really happens when you invoke the specific method.

Did it help you?

Comment: 1. Yeah, I really lack the quote (I edited your answer); 2. The problem is that this value can be change futurelly, by other method that access the `$globals` (but there is another matter); 3. Yeah! The `bind` name sounds better for me. I'll work with this, now, for this cases :) Thanks